# Designing a custom edit control similar to hotmail style "To" box

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am desiging a custom control for use in my application which simulates a hotmail style "To" textbox which lets the user enter semicolon delimited strings. The control behaves like a textbox, on each ener press or entering semicolon a box(a textblock infact) gets created containing text entered which can be manipulated individually.

The control is implemented by means of a listview with its ItemPresenter set to a WrapPanel

The XAML looks like below:

```
<ListView x:Name="col" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <local:MyWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="400"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BoxView}" />
<Style.Triggers>
 <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Edit">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BoxViewEdit}" />
 </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The control template for the listviewitems (boxes) looks like:

```
      <DataTemplate x:Key="BoxView">
       <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Brown" Background="Beige" Margin="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="6" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,5,5,0" Height="20" Text="{Binding XPath=''}"/>
                    <DockPanel  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="edit8.png" MouseLeftButtonUp="edit_MouseLeftButtonUp" ToolTip="Edit" Margin=" 10,0,0,0"></Image>
                        <Image Source="cancel8.png" MouseLeftButtonUp ="cancel_MouseLeftButtonUp" ToolTip="Remove" Margin=" 5,0,5,0"></Image>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Actually the listview is data bound to a set of xmlnodes having common parent.
The look and feel of the control has to be given such that it looks like a text box.
Now, I have the listview items bound to the xml nodes of an xml document, to show the textbox I add an empty xmlnode in the document and change the control template of the coressponding listviewitem so that it shows as a textbox.
On pressing enter in the text box a new xml node gets appended to the underlying xml at second last position containing innertext set to the textbox text(last positon is dummy node)

The template used for textbox is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BoxViewEdit">
  <TextBox  Margin="0,5,5,0" Background="White" MaxWidth="400" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding XPath=''}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But the idea of adding an empty dummy xmlnode in the underlying source xml so that i could simulate editing of the listview seems hacky. Is there any cleaner way of doing this.

What i want is to wrap the text box as shown in figure with the contents of the wrappanel seamlessly without adding it to the wrappanel itself by means of creating a dummy xmlnode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found some solutions; you can check out the responses and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443728/tag-editing-in-a-wpf-textbox).