# Tag editing in a WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox

I want to implement a custom TextBox that will allow me to edit tags. Hotmail's "To" TextBox is the best example I can think of:

[image]

Also Facebook's "To" implements the same concept:

[image]

Oh yeah, and StackOverflow does it too to tag a question :)

Does anyone have some experience in building something like that in WPF? What would be the first steps that I should make?

Comment: Just want to let people know that DevExpress also has this control in their library: [TokenEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/17088/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Token-Edit-Control)

Comment: But it is for Winforms not WPF?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this Tokenizing control does most of what you're looking for:

http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/

Comment: Your answer was helpful. I also found another helpful resource (Silverlight): http://www.thesilvermethod.com/Default.aspx?Id=IntroducingTagBox

Comment: This is a superb base control.  I was easily able to take the concepts from the article for the tokenizing control and extend them into a re-useable and portable search suggest control.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try the following:

- implement a `TagEditor`, which has the functionality to edit a single Tag (based on an AutoComplete TextBox that is swapped with a TextBlock once an existing Tag has been recognized or editing is ended)
- create an DataTemplate that uses the `TagEditor`
- create an ItemsControl that utilizes the DataTemplate

that breaks it down to three challenges, of which only the first is a bit tricky, but solveable with the given keywords and stackoverflow ;-)